# Docker remote error: tls: handshake failure

Tags: docker, ssl, handshake

I installed Docker version "Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b" and when I try to use the docker pull command, like "docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest" by administration permission in PowerShell and Windows 10, I receive the message error --> remote error: tls: handshake failure

```
PS C:\temp> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      17763  0


PS C:\temp> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
PS C:\temp> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
2017-latest: Pulling from mssql/server
error pulling image configuration: Get https://mcreus0.cdn.mscr.io/aba285c624a04409823b708c7a50e7b9-jttfjm99vo//docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/a8/a8343d3ce21c1a659f3d3148a6c90a05b08abce53101806867fab2754f84ac8c/data?P1=1584881883&P2=1&P3=1&P4=x8kUQevcxTM5raMCzrWz%2Ft93x8O09YNv7TsqPTN2828%3D&se=2020-03-22T12%3A58%3A03Z&sig=BzDZVyRHWd8i8sQ4l44TwTGkQBfKQB9FlYu8eOWIhM4%3D&sp=r&sr=b&sv=2016-05-31&regid=aba285c624a04409823b708c7a50e7b9: remote error: tls: handshake failure
PS C:\temp>
```

Someone know how to solve this problem?

PS: At home, i've the same enviroment (windows version, docker version) and the docker pull command is Ok.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your are behind a corporate proxy at work.

Starting from version 18.09, docker removed support for older tls ciphers.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2922#issuecomment-444431310

After docker downgrade to a version (less) < 18.09, the `tls: handshake failure` error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

After installing the certificate of https://hub.docker.com/ my TLS handshake issue was resolved. I wasn't able to pull any image from the docker hub this solved my issue.

To download and install the certificate:

[image]

connection secure > more information > view certificate

Right click on the crl file downloaded and then choose install CRL to install the certificate

Comment: This works, should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

May be due to corporate policy, firewalls, etc.
In my case it was a matter of turning down company's VPN.