# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to view software running in docker containers via url

Tags: docker, web-development-server, network-security

I'm new to Docker, and have been reconstructing a test environment with instructions that were left to me by the previous developer.

We have several in-house pieces of job tracking software that both the outside clients and internal employees can access.

The job tracking software has a few dependencies that require a mailhog container to be spun up, and a second container which contains all of the other required sub software.

Despite my amateur knowledge on the subject, and the complexity of the software, I successfully installed Docker with the required Linux Kernels and Ubuntu.
I pulled the required images I needed, and successfully built the other ones.
I configured the in-house software with all of the testing settings enabled, and have it all grouped in the proper file directory.

By all intents and purposes, it should be configured fine.
The trouble starts with starting the containers.

The command line prompt "docker-compose up -d" pointed in the proper sub-directory throws this error:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": remote error: tls: handshake failure

I figured screw it, I'll build it right from the Docker Desktop instead of using command line, and it worked! The two containers I needed successfully built.

I even ran the docker test command to make sure they were really running.

So here's where the trouble just gets worse.

The ex-developer states the jobtracking software can then be viewed in browser using this "https://localhost/jobtracker/"

The page doesn't load, and then throws err_connection_refused error.

I am at my wits end with trouble shooting, because I quite simply don't have the networking or development knowledge to search the right things, AND to make matters even more frustrating is the remote outsourced devs have their environment up and running, despite using the exact same instructions I have.

So I'm down to two possible issues. Either somewhere in the set-up process, I messed something up, OR my office network security is breaking something. However, I was told by our lead IT specialist, I should have all of the same network permissions the outsourced guys on the vpns have.

I am here now reaching out on several docker web sources to find a solution.

I am on Windows 10.

Thankfully my employers are pretty cool about me learning as I go, and understand the technical difficulties. I just don't want to squander the opportunity, and would like to make some progress.

Comment: No way this isn't related to your initial "TLS handshake error" - also it's a good bet your IT dept is mistaken.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64718384/8896855 and other answers to the same issue

Comment: Also, you're trying to connect to localhost (same as 0.0.0.0 IP) with an unmapped port (default is 80).  Try with the added docker argument " -p 80:80 " - this will connect to that port in your container.

Comment: I'm ending my word day here in a few minutes, so forgive my rushed response. The old dev had the jobtracking container set to port 443/tcp. As I said, I am total novice with Docker. How can I ensure that port setting allows me access via the browser/url?

Comment: Should be " -p 80:443 ", but could be the other way around depending on how they configured it (it'll be explicitly stated in the compose .yaml file).  If you find you need to specify another port in your browser's url, that'd look like :  http://localhost:8080 or similar